# Save texbox text to SQL Server in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, textbox

I have a website in ASP.NET and I have a textbox that the user type in text. I want to save this into a SQL Server database that saves all other data from site. I have tried several ways and got to the code below. It throws up the error below
Any help as I'm lost on this now....

Error:

> The name 'txtName' does not exist in the current context Step9.aspx.cs 67

Page markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Step9.aspx.cs" Inherits="Step1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="question" id="question">
        <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                Name:<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="140" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Insert" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

C# codebehind:

```
protected void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO learners (stickTwistBefore) VALUES (@stickTwistBefore)"))
        {
             using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stickTwistBefore", name);
                 cmd.Connection = con;

                 con.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 con.Close();
             }
        }
    }

    // this.BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to **indent** your code and markup ....

Comment: Is the `Insert` method on the Master Page code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have specified `Step1` class name as Inherits attribute. Ensure that it matches the class name in your Step9.aspx.cs file. I guess `Step9` but just confirm.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Step9.aspx.cs" Inherits="Step1" %>
```

Comment: Mohsin    Thanks for your answer. I have never heard of the designer.cs file. What other code should it have in or do I just add the code line to the aspx.cs file ?

Comment: @StephenB I have just updated the answer. Hopefully, it will fix your issue